# How to make the Android Device listen to a particular port number

Tags: android, sockets, http, http-post, port

I am new to android and is trying to develop an application. I have a local server that has the address  like `http://abc:9070/`

**i.e:** the server is running only on port number 9070 in my laptop.

Now i want to debug my program using a android device and i have to make sure that the android device listens to port number 9070, So that i can make the post http request call to the url and fetch some information.

Can someone tell me how can i make my device to listen to port number 9070?

Also can someone tell me whether changing default port number of adb solve this.

I have tried a lot to search for a solution. But i am not able to come up with any good answers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody has expressed an opinion yet. May be the question is not clear, at least I found it very difficult to understand what you are trying to do.

You say you have a server (laptop) listening on port 9070 and you want a device to connect to this server thru this port? Is that right?

Have you try, from your device, launch the navigator and connect to that address? `http://abc:9070`

Anyway, the java code to make a socket connection is something similar to this:

```
try
{
     Socket clientSocket = new Socket("YOUR_LAPTOP_IP", 9070);
     // 1024 is an arbitrary number, could be 512, 65535, etc
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int ret=0;
     while ((ret=clientSocket.getInputStream().read(buffer)) > 0)
     {
        // from now on it's up to you what to do with the data you read
     }
     clientSocket.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```